# Typescript zustand middlewares types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript, zustand

If you remove the ternary expression and try to create a store separately, then everything works. And if I use a ternary with different shells, it gives the error given below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZfWN.png)

```
    import { create } from 'zustand';
    import { devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';
    import { immer } from 'zustand/middleware/immer';
    import { createSettingsSlice } from './settingsSlice';
    import { USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE } from '../env';
    import { RootStore, StoreSet } from './index';
    import { createFamilySlice } from './familySlice';

    const store = (set: StoreSet) => ({
      ...createSettingsSlice(set),
      ...createFamilySlice(set),
    });`your text`
    
    export const useStore: (<T>(cb: (store: RootStore) => T) => T) = create<RootStore>()(
      USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE ? devtools(immer(store)) : immer(store),
    );
```

Here is such an error appears

```
>! ERROR in src/store/useStore.ts:15:3
>! TS2345: Argument of type 'StateCreator<{ family: { activeMemberId?: string | undefined; setActiveMemberId: (userId: string | undefined) => void; members: UserInfo[]; setMembers: (members: UserInfo[]) => void; }; settings: { ...; }; }, [], [...], { ...; }> | StateCreator<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateCreator<RootStore, [], [["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]], RootStore>'.
>! Type 'StateCreator<{ family: { activeMemberId?: string | undefined; setActiveMemberId: (userId: string | undefined) => void; members: UserInfo[]; setMembers: (members: UserInfo[]) => void; }; settings: { ...; }; }, [], [...], { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'StateCreator<RootStore, [], [["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]], RootStore>'.
>! Type 'StateCreator<{ family: { activeMemberId?: string | undefined; setActiveMemberId: (userId: string | undefined) => void; members: UserInfo[]; setMembers: (members: UserInfo[]) => void; }; settings: { ...; }; }, [], [...], { ...; }>' is not assignable to type '{ $$storeMutators?: [["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]] | undefined; }'.
>! Types of property '$$storeMutators' are incompatible.
>! Type '[["zustand/immer", never]] | undefined' is not assignable to type '[["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]] | undefined'.
>! Type '[["zustand/immer", never]]' is not assignable to type '[["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]]'.
>! Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2.
>! 13 |
>! 14 | export const useStore: (<T>(cb: (store: RootStore) => T) => T) = create<RootStore>()(
>! 15 |   USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE ? devtools(immer(store)) : immer(store),
>!        |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>! 16 | );
>! 17 |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D179.png)

As soon as I tried to fix it, in the end, write ts-ignore and that's it`

Comment: Could you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me to take a look at?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZfWN.png

Answer (score 0):

When you provide `USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE ? devtools(immer(store)) : immer(store)` as an argument to the `create` function, it tries to infer the type of the argument and since it's an expression involving ternary operator, there can be two types resulting from this expression, namely -

```ts
// StateCreator type is from the zustand library
StateCreator<{}, [], [["zustand/immer", never]]> | StateCreator<{}, [], [["zustand/devtools", never], ["zustand/immer", never]]>
```

Now, as per the [signature](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/src/vanilla.ts#L48) of the `create` function that you're calling, it's going to restrict the return type to be either one of these, to see that in action, you can do this -

```ts
import { Mutate, StoreApi } from 'zustand';
import { devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';
import { immer } from 'zustand/middleware/immer';

declare const USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE: boolean;

type RootStore = Record<any, any>;

const store = (set: StoreSet) => ({
}); `your text`

const res = USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE ? devtools(immer(store)) : immer(store);

type Result = Mutate<StoreApi<RootStore>,typeof res>
// Here the type of Result is never
```

which is why it gives that error. An alternative to this is to use the [other signature](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/src/vanilla.ts#L44) which allows you to provide second type parameter which can pass the return type check for the `create` function. Here's what you can do -

```ts
    import { create } from 'zustand';
    import { devtools } from 'zustand/middleware';
    import { immer } from 'zustand/middleware/immer';
    import { createSettingsSlice } from './settingsSlice';
    import { USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE } from '../env';
    import { RootStore, StoreSet } from './index';
    import { createFamilySlice } from './familySlice';

    const store = (set: StoreSet) => ({
      ...createSettingsSlice(set),
      ...createFamilySlice(set),
    });

    type StoreType = [["zustand/devtools" | "zustand/immer", never], ["zustand/immer" | "zustand/devtools", never]];

    export const useStore: (<T>(cb: (store: RootStore) => T) => T) = create<RootStore, StoreType>(USE_DEV_TOOLS_FOR_STORE ? devtools(immer(store)) : immer(store));
```

And that should take care of it. Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQGjgWQFcYtc4BlGaNAQTGDgF84AzKCEOAcgC9CBnEgDsAJlwDcAKFCRYiOCLQA3KhAA2-Jq3adeA4SID0IYCJFq0AdwzoJ08NHhJQINFC1sO3PoIyjjpuZWNmiGLm52kpKKyGohKBBCgnAAquQAogD6ACLpAGqZACoA8sUAMuSZAGLFAEqZ5CW16QBccABGEOqYQlKSMACeYGhwtV0wlNRwALyjaMjQIgA8fgN4qwB8UoPDFFTo5GjwswAUYDYwwBhqbWMQE-sjAD5wAAoXV2pLdw-UG3AvE4nXzYW7jSboACUM3+PwhzzeH2u33Bjw2kLw6DAcWQaAA-G1Ot0-AC4IRRGgWMAhGgRNDpv8lBBTH1JAskvBBFNTvwjm14YcYPT-icEJJGJDxHAAAYDCCEdzYAAeMGlUR2I3hhSGI1mAG09QAiHwGQyKFRdDSG0nG-R+IzhKCGvA0pRuAC6eCNJvtYRAridNp9-nNqitLuUHvdfTQStk8HZyQEaHhbROS0KGxOyHaaa56DB93hwrghRLZZmKHQpBRRceeC1OqzkjgrdSGRy+SKpQq1TqDSa6TgeIUyjD-BOjuBj0h0LaU-zaEhkklQA) to the playground.